# Using Sqlite in WinRT(VB.Net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to follow the below mentioned tutorials in trying to use sqlite for my windwows store app..

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Using-SQLite-in-Windows-Store-Apps
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/06/05/howto-video-using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

But all the videos and articles where in C# and I have a small problem here..

When using sqlite as described in the above links it works fine with c# as shown below adding `SQLite.cs` and `SQLiteAsync.cs`:

Now I would like to add a class for creating a table as shown and it works for C#:

```
 public class person
    {

        [MaxLength(5), PrimaryKey]

        public String name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public String address { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(11)]
        public Double phone { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Now If I do the same thing for my VB.Net project by adding same SQLite it shows me as shown below:

The class creating in VB gives me errors as shown:

[image]
[image]

an anyone say me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I don't think a VB project can contain a .CS file. However you can compile CS files in a separate assembly and add a reference to this assembly to the VB project and use it.

Comment: @Pawel is right, you can't mix and match programming languages within a single project.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time...

The workaround:

1. Download&install [sqlite-winrt81-3080803.vsix](http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-winrt81-3080803.vsix) or browse [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to select the product.
2. Create the project. Go to project properties and add the reference to SQlite  for Windows Runtime, in extensions tab.
3. Install SQLitePortable package from Nuget.

[image: Code]

I hope it helps.